# Plesk 12 does not create IUSR_site_name user

Tags: permissions, plesk

In our Plesk 9.5 installation Plesk automatically created the user `IUSR_site_name`, for example, for a subscription with a username `afl`, Plesk created the `IUSR_afl user`.

Then, when we need the web users to have read and write permissions to a server directory, for example /httpdocs/data, we could give to the `IUSR_afl` user read and write permissions.

How can we accomplish the same with Plesk 12? How can we give the web user read and write permissions in order to create and modify some files in specific directories? From what we have tried, Plesk 12 does not create the `IUSR_afl` user.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk creates sites which are working in application pools which working under `IWPG_<user name>` user.

There is also setting on Domain > Hosting Settings > "Additional write/modify permissions" which provide write permissions to app pool's user.